# Find the volume of water of depth $x$ of a conical tank

Tags: algebra-precalculus, volume

**Find $V(x)$ if $V(x)$ is the volume of water of depth $x$ contained in a conical tank with vertice downwards. The tank is $8$ meters high and its diameter in the highest part is $6$ meters.**

Answer:

> $V(x)=3\pi\dfrac{x^3}{64}$.

---

I think that a sketch of the situation is:

[image: Sketch]

I tried to use the formula of the conical volume: $V=\dfrac{\pi r^2h}{3}$, where $r=\dfrac62=3$ and $h=8$, but then $V=\dfrac{\pi3^28}3=24\pi$, which 1) does not depend on the depth and 2) does not have the same coefficients of the answer.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your $r=3$ and $h=8$ are for the entire tank. But instead, you need to use the radius and height of the cone that has height $x$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth ohh so the volume of that part would be $V(x)=\dfrac{\pi(3-x)^2(8-x)}{3}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you found the volume of the *whole* conical tank, not the water.

Imagine taking a vertical cross-section of the tank:

[image]

The volume of the water is given by

$$V = \frac 1 3 \pi r^2 x$$

What is $r$? It can be shown that the triangle formed by the water is similar in the geometric sense to the entire triangle. Then we can set up a proportion:

$$\frac{\text{radius of the tank}}{\text{height of the tank}} = \frac{\text{radius of the water}}{\text{height of the water}} \implies \frac{3}{8} = \frac r x \implies r = \frac 3 8 x$$

Thus,

$$V = \frac 1 3 \pi \left( \frac 3 8 x \right)^2 x = \frac 1 3 \cdot \pi \cdot \frac{9}{64} \cdot x^2 \cdot x = \frac{3\pi}{64}x^3$$

matching the answer.